# how to display pricebook record type on pricebook list view

Tags: lightning

How can i display the record type on the list view of the pricebook object. please help me to show the record type on the list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use formula field in pricebook.

Formula as RecordType.Name

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that we cant access the record type on pricebook object list view.
i found alternate solution i create one formula field and select special formula and select record type and save.